# Laravel and VueJS with blade templates

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vuejs2

The new laravel comes with a built-in VueJs. But what I need is one instance of vuejs binded to body tag for the whole app. How can I achieve this ? Is there a way of binding vue directly on body element, even though its not recommended ? The purpose is only using vue to make an API calls for certain parts of my app, but I need vue to be available globally and without binding to specific element, which will destroy my current app

Update Code:
default layout - laravel

```
...
</head>
<body id="app" class="{{isActiveRoute('home')}}">
...
</body>
```

resources/assets/app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));

const app = new Vue({

    el: '#app',

    components: ['example'],

    data: {
        name: 'test'
    },

    methods: {

        addToCart() {
            console.log('add to cart');
        }
    },
```

Comment: You should explain what you tried and what failed or what errors you are getting by showing code snippets. You can just give an id to your body and bind it to your vuejs instance.

Comment: I've tried to bind to html with id and body with id, but this way is not working

Comment: I think your main point is using Vue.js without instantiating it or without the use of components ...if this is your concern don't use Vue.js

Comment: the question is not about should I use it or no.

Comment: @d123546 as I told you, it's better if you post your code. Otherwise there is no way to know what's going wrong.

Comment: @MerhawiFissehaye as you can see, nothing special, default codes.

Comment: What were you expecting to see? You have instantiated the Vue component correctly. But it does nothing in the code you posted. If you were expecting to see the result of the `console.log` statement from the `addToCart` method, you should call it somewhere in your template.